# how to set SQLite COLLATE NOCASE colum using linq2db with CreateTable?

Tags: sqlite, linq2db

Please help me how to set column collation if table is created from class definition using linq2db ?
I'm using linq2db 2.6.3 to get data from SQLite local application database

There is a work mode in the application that creates database if it does not exists.

It looks like `Code first` approach and db is built using DataConnection.CreateTable extension

```
void CreateTableIfNotExists<TDto>(DataConnection conn)
{
    var sp = conn.DataProvider.GetSchemaProvider();
    var dbSchema = sp.GetSchema(conn);
    var tableName = typeof(TDto).Name;
    if (!dbSchema.Tables.Any(t => t.TypeName == tableName))
    {
        //no required table-create it
        conn.CreateTable<TDto>();
    }
}
```

By default SQLite has case sensitive column collation for text columns.

I'd like to create text columns with `COLLATE NOCASE` like

```
create table Test (
Name nvachar(255) null COLLATE NOCASE
)
```

The only one way I found to do it is to set column format and to append `COLLATE NOCASE` to the format string, like below

```
// modified class from linq2db SQLiteTests.cs 
[Table(Name = "CreateTableTest", Schema = "IgnoreSchema")]
public class CreateTableTest
{
    [PrimaryKey, Identity]
    public int Id;
    [Column(CreateFormat = "{0} {1} {2} {3} COLLATE NOCASE")]
    public string Name;
}
```

It works but is there more convenient way to achieve the same?

Comment: Nope, right now it is the only supported approach. We thought about adding collations support for `create table` before but there were no requests for it. You can create feature request

Comment: @DLuk I see, thank you. Seems that those cases are rare enough so I will use CreateFormat property.